# Microsoft Outlook 2013 IMAP server alert

Tags: imap, microsoft-outlook-2013, alert

I keep getting this pop up alert in MS Outlook 2013: "Your IMAP server wants to alert you to the following: cannot move folder into nonexistent folder"

I have no idea how to fix this.  Apparently I tried to move a folder to somewhere that doesn't exist and don't know how to move it back to wherever it came from.  Any ideas how to fix this???

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/receive-pop-up-your-imap-server-wants-to-alert-you/6d789de9-c792-4d33-9677-e2c3617bc5ac) can help.

Comment: Thanks but wasn't helpful